# How can usual user access to /dev/sda file

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, privileges

My OS is Debian9 and I need use command `smartctl` in my script to get some hard drive info. But due to usual user have some special environment variable， I can't execute this script by `sudo`. So I execute command `ls -l /dev/ | grep sd`, and I found the group of `/dev/sdb` is `disk`. So I edit the `/etc/group` add the usual user to the `disk` group. Then run the script, it still show `Smartctl open device: /dev/sda failed: Permission denied`. How can I slove this problem? thankyou all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a way.

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/smartctl
sudo ln /usr/sbin/smartctl /usr/bin/smartctl
```

In this way I can finally execute command without using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run the whole script via sudo; change it to run just smartctl via sudo.

Alternatively, use the /etc/sudoers option `env_keep` to preserve the environment variables:

```
Defaults env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL PAGER"

Defaults!someuser env_keep += "API_CLIENT_ID API_CLIENT_SECRET"
```

---

Giving full read/write access to the system disk creates a huge security issue – the user can now read/write all files belonging to any user; for example, they could even recover deleted data, or overwrite /etc/sudoers and give themselves unlimited root access.

Besides that, SCSI commands using SG_IO require more privileges than just ordinary device writes – usually they require process [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) such as CAP_SYS_ADMIN or CAP_SYS_RAWIO. Assigning these privileges essentially makes the user *root* in everything but name.